# Log4cxx How to build C++ application with ODBC support

Tags: c++, postgresql, odbc, unixodbc, log4cxx

On RHEL 8, using Postgres 12.

When I attempt to run a C++ application that uses log4cxx and an ODBCAppender to write some statements to a Postgres DB, I get the following error message:

```
log4cxx: Can not activate ODBCAppender unless compiled with ODBC support.
```

The above error message occurs when the following line is called in the C++ application:

```
PropertyConfigurator::configure(homedir + "/.myapp_config/myapp_log_config");
```

What do I need to do to compile my C++ application with ODBC support??

Answer (score 0):

That error is being printed from [log4cxx itself](https://github.com/apache/logging-log4cxx/blob/1649f33ecc306af814a101053b15456f4aed37a5/src/main/cpp/odbcappender.cpp#L138).  When the library was compiled, ODBC was not available, so support was not compiled in.  Make sure that the ODBC headers are installed and re-compile the log4cxx library.  On Debian/Ubuntu, this should be as easy as installing the `unixodbc-dev` package on your system; I'm not sure what the package name on RHEL is.

Comment: Ok, I have already installed unixODBC-devel, but didn't realize I had to re-build log4cxx again.   Thank you very much for that information, I will give it a try.